# Getting variable uninitialized in Perl using stat

Tags: perl, portability, epoch, stat, initialization

I'm working on a script which shows the age of an existing file and then automatically delete it after about 4 hours of being there (presumed maintenance window). I've been trying to test my output with the `stat` function in Perl. We have multiple boxes, some running Linux and Solaris, so this is the most portable way to do it.  I'm trying to get epoch time.

```
use File::stat;
$file  = "samplefile"; 
$mtime = (stat($file))[9];
if (!defined $file){
    print "No file specified\n";
    exit 1; 
}
printf("%d", @mtime);
```

I know `stat()` returns a `@_`, so I tried to change my datatype to this. But it keeps coming back saying that `mtime` has not been initialized. Why does it say that?

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`!

Comment: `stat` returns *a list*, it's impossible to return an array (e.g. `@_`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You print the contents of `@mtime`, but you placed the result in `$mtime`. Always use `use strict; use warnings;`. It would have found your problem.

Your code should look like one of the following:

- Without File::stat (`stat` returns a list):

  ```
  use strict;
  use warnings;
  my $file  = "samplefile"; 
  my $mtime = (stat($file))[9];
  die "Can't stat file: $!\n" if !defined($mtime);
  printf("%d\n", $mtime);
  ```

  `(EXPR)[9]` returns the 10th element of the list `EXPR` returns, or undef if the list isn't that long. This is a scalar you assigned to `$mtime`, not `@mtime`.
- With File::stat (`stat` returns an object):

  ```
  use strict;
  use warnings;
  use File::stat;
  my $file  = "samplefile"; 
  my $stat = stat($file);
  die "Can't stat file: $!\n" if !$stat;
  printf("%d\n", $stat->mtime);
  ```

Comment: OMG!  It worked.  So declaring it and referencing mtime did the trick!  Thanks so much.  That really really helped a lot.

Answer (score 4):

You are accessing the array `@mtime`, but you assign a value to the scalar `$mtime`. They are not the same variable.

If you had used

```
use strict;
```

You would be aware of this problem right away:

```
Global symbol "@mtime" requires explicit package name at ...
```

You should always use

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Not doing so will cause you lots of extra work and "mysterious" bugs.